# Produce API docs via code using API Blueprint

Tags: api, apiblueprint

Is it possible to produce/generate documentation using `API Blueprint` tool from Restful API code and If so how to use this tool any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a way how to generate a description of your API from the code then API Blueprint isn't probably the best choice as we believe it should represent the contract between everybody involved in the API design lifecycle. This is also the reason why we have built the testing tool – Dredd – https://github.com/apiaryio/dredd

With Dredd you can test your API implementation is matching to your blueprint. It wouldn't make much sense if the blueprint would be generated from the implementation.

Hope this does clarify.

Comment: thanks for your reply...from where to download the blueprint editor..do u have any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by downloading Blueprint editor? Are you looking for syntax highlighting tool?

Comment: yes i want a tool for rendering the blueprint (.md) files

Comment: If you want to render APIB offline you may want to check: [aglio](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/aglio/); if you're looking for syntax highlighting, you may want to check the [tools section](https://apiblueprint.org/) here.

Comment: Please see the answer above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97298/discussion-between-mohammed-and-vincenzo).